# For some reason this AJAX will work in one project, but not in another

Tags: php, ajax

All of the directories are correct, I've included jQuery and the PHP script is simply echoing a string. I've checked everything and I can't find anything wrong with it. Here's the code:

```
// script.php
echo "hello";

// HTML
<button type="button"></button>

// jQuery/AJAX
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'script.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Why isn't this working? I seriously can not see a single problem... Did I make a foolish mistake, or if not what are some possible things that could be causing this error?

Also, if I decided to, how can I make it so that I don't have to use "url: 'script.php'" and instead I include script.php in the page with the jQuery/AJAX code?

Thanks for the help, I've been building a project but I keep having to ask questions every 5 minutes due to the tediousness with programming :)

EDIT ***

I've looked in the console and found this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". Here's a screenshot[image: the error in the console]

Comment: Where you have included your `jquery.js`? please provide seperate code for seperate files.

Comment: see path for 'script.php' file.if it is not working it will give some error for sure,visit your console and see what it says.

Comment: I believe `$("button")` is an array of one element. Any selector except ID -- is array. In your case it should be `$("button")[0].click(...`

Comment: nope, 0 errors. the code for the jquery is <script src="jquery.js"></script> I have jQuery installed locally

Comment: @RubenKazumov I've used this exact script in another folder, and it worked fine, so it's definitely not that

Comment: how are you opening the web page in browser? `http://...` or `\User\Sites\...`?

Comment: Im on a PC on WAMP, so I'm using the localhost/ directory

Comment: somehow i ran the script again, and now it's showing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined* error jQuery can't have been included.

There might be a few possible reasons for this:

- You forgot to add the script tag for it
- You put the jQuery script tag after the one with your code, make sure jQuery is first
- The script tag or surrounding tags are malformed (maybe you didn't close the tag before it or the head tag isn't close)
- The URL might be wrong
- If you're hosting the file it might not have been uploaded
- You might have a script somewhere which is overriding $ or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try using this complete set of code.

Couple of checks:

- Check that script.php is spelt correctly and that the filename is not scripts.php.
- Ensure that the script.php page contain the following code:

> ```
>    <?php
>      echo "hello";
>    ?>
> ```

**Complete code file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'scripts.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <button type="button"></button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
<button type="button" id="btn"></button>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

// jQuery/AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'script.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```